# Inexplicable behavior of WebClient.DownloadFile

Tags: c#, file, webclient

In my console application I'm downloading an .xlsx-file from a given URL. If I set the download path to "C:\Temp\Test.xlsx" the download works as expected and I can open the file in Excel. But if I set the path to "C:\SomeFolder\SomeSubfolder\Test.xlsx" I get a folder with the name 'Test.xlsx' at the specified location.

Here is the code where I download the file:

```
public void DownloadFile(string sourceUrl, string targetPath
{
    try
    {
        CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(targetPath);

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            webClient.DownloadFile(sourceUrl, targetPath);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.Write(e);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And here is the method where I create the directory if it doesn't exist yet:

```
private void CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(string targetPath)
{
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(targetPath)))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
    }
}
```

---

Result with `targetPath` set to "C:\Temp\Test.xlsx":

[image]

Result with `targetPath` set to "C:\SomeFolder\SomeSubfolder\Test.xlsx":

[image]

Is there any reason why my file is saved as a folder and not as a file?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What *exactly* are the folders in question? If you copy the file from `c:\temp` to the other folder, what do you see?

Comment: paste all your code ? you probably are doing something else wrong, eg a call to Directory.CreateDirectory somewhere. 
Try deleting the folder `Test.xlsx` and run your program again. If the directory is recreated that is your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the directory from the target path. Change this line

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
```

to

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(new System.IO.FileInfo(targetPath).DirectoryName));
```